# C++ a value of type "char" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *"

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, char

I'm getting the error from the title when I try to initialize a two dimensional array.

```
//strX and strY are strings
int m = strX.length();
int n = strY.length();

//declare two dynamic 2-Dimensional array of variable length B is m X n
char** B;

InitializeTable(&B, m, n);

//function below
InitializeTable(char***B, int m, int n)
{
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; i++)
    {
        B[i][j] = ' '; //getting the error on the equals sign
    }
}
```

I think is something very simple I'm missing. Thank you!

Comment: char*** would be a 3-dimensional character array. B[i][j] is a char*.

Comment: char***B....Are you sure of triple pointer?

Comment: `char** B;` declares an *Unitialized pointer to pointer to char* - it points nowhere until you allocate memory for the pointers, and then allocate memory for what the pointers point to.

Comment: C++ is not a script language. The first lines from `int m...` up to `InitializeTable(&B, ...)` must be inside a function (like `main`). Furthermore you declare B as a multidimensional array, but you don't assign memory for it. This will result into a memory access violation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ***"Doahh...."*** moment is:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; i++)
```

Why are you using `i++` in a `j` loop?

Beyond the typo, you would generally want to pass only `m` and `n` to `InitializeTable`, declare `B` local to `InitializeTable`, allocate `m` pointers and then `n` chars and assign the beginning address for each allocation of chars to the successive pointer and return `B` and assign the return back in `main()`.<sup>**[1]**</sup> This prevents passing the *address of* `B` as a parameter and thereby becoming a *3-Star Programmer* (not a compliment). That said, there is educational purpose in the exercise.

When you declare `char **B;` in `main()`, `B` is an unitialized *pointer to pointer to char*. It has its very own address (the pointer `B`), but it points nowhere (actually the address held by `B` is indeterminate and likely just whatever was at the address of `B` at the time it was declared. You cannot use `B` for any other purpose at this point other than assigning the address of another `char **` pointer that has been properly initialized.

When you pass the *address of* `B` to `InitializeTable`, e.g.

```
    InitializeTable (&B, m, n);
```

and `B` receives the address, you must allocate `m` pointers and assign the beginning address for the pointers as the *value held by* `B` (not as the 3-star pointer address). To do this, you must dereference `B` in `InitializeTable`. (just as you would declare `int *a, b = 5;` and then make `a` point to `b` with `a = &b`, to change the value pointed to by `b` you would dereference and assing, e.g. `*b = 10;`) Example:

```
void InitializeTable (char ***B, int m, int n)
{
    *B = new char*[m];
```

By using the `new` operator, you have allocated storage for `m` pointers (`char*`) and assigned the beginning address to the pointer `B` in `main()`, `*B` in `InitializeTable`.

Now you need to allocate `n` chars for each pointer and assign the beginning address for each block to each pointer. However, since we are 3-star programmers, and have one additional level of indirection to deal with, instead of assigning to `B[i]`, we must derefence `B` first -- but, C++ *Operator Precedence* causes `[]` to bind tighter (has higher precedence) than the `'*'` dereference operator, so you must enclose `*B` in parenthesis first, e.g. `(*B)[i]` with:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        (*B)[i] = new char[n];
```

Now you can assign your spaces as the characters to initialize the character values in `(*B)[i]`, e.g.

```
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            (*B)[i][j] = ' ';
```

(**note:** all `j`s in the loop definition)

That's all there is to it. Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void InitializeTable (char ***B, int m, int n)
{
    *B = new char*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        (*B)[i] = new char[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            (*B)[i][j] = ' ';
    }
}

int main (void) {

    std::string strX = "cats",
                strY = "dogs";

    //strX and strY are strings
    int m = strX.length();
    int n = strY.length();

    //declare two dynamic 2-Dimensional array of variable length B is m X n
    char **B;

    InitializeTable (&B, m, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            std::cout << " '" << B[i][j] << "'";
        std::cout << '\n';
        delete[] B[i];      /* free each block of characters */
    }
    delete[] B;     /* free pointers */
}
```

(don't forget to free both the memory holding the characters, as well as the pointers you allocate)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/threestarc++
 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

$ ./bin/threestarc++
     ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
     ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
     ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
     ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '

```
$ valgrind ./bin/threestarc++
==784== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==784== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==784== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==784== Command: ./bin/threestarc++
==784==
 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
 ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '
==784==
==784== HEAP SUMMARY:
==784==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==784==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 72,810 bytes allocated
==784==
==784== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==784==
==784== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==784== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

**footnotes:**

**1.** Actually you would want to declare a vector of vector `<char>` (e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` in `main()` and pass a reference to `InitializeTable` for initialization letting C++ handle the memory management for you.

Comment: Thanks for the incredible explanation!

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Pointers are not that difficult to make friends with as long as you remember, they are just a variable that holds the address to something else as its value. Each level removed from the value by holding an address (level of indirection) simply takes a dereference (a `'*'`) to remove, `char *`, one level of indirection, takes one dereference to reference the value, `char **` takes two, etc... Each `'&'` (address of) you take, adds one level, `'*'` takes one away. Keep *operator precedence* in mind and you will have no further problems. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this: Each set of `[]` removes a `*`. Simple case: `char *string = "fred";` `string[0]` removes a `[]` so you get the data (f)

You have `***B` and `B[i][j]` so you still have one `*` to go...

The fact that you have not initialized any memory is also a problem...

You should also give a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

When passing multidimensional arrays, I think it's easier to think of them as references.  So in `InitializeTable()` you can just declare B to be a reference to `char**`, ie. `char**&`.

```
//strX and strY are strings
int m = strX.length();
int n = strY.length();

//declare two dynamic 2-Dimensional array of variable length B is m X n
char** B;

InitializeTable(B, m, n);               // Just pass in B, which will be a reference to char**.

//function below
InitializeTable(char**&B, int m, int n) // Declare B to be a refernce to char**.
{
    B = new char * [m];                 // Allocate for first dimension, note these are pointers.
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        B[i] = new char[n];             // Allocate for second dimension, note these are chars.
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)     // Note: you had i++ here.
        {
            B[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `InitializeTable()`, you need to dereference `B` before you can then index into the array.  Also, you are not allocating any memory for the array.  Try something like this:

```
void InitializeTable(char** *B, int m, int n)
{
    *B = new char*[m];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        (*B)[i] = new char[n];

        for (int j = 0; j < n; i++)
        {
            (*B)[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

...

int m = strX.length();
int n = strY.length();

char** B;
InitializeTable(&B, m, n);

...

for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    delete[] B[i];
delete[] B;
```

Alternatively, pass `B` by reference instead of by pointer:

```
void InitializeTable(char** &B, int m, int n)
{
    B = new char*[m];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        B[i] = new char[n];

        for (int j = 0; j < n; i++)
        {
            B[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

...

int m = strX.length();
int n = strY.length();

char** B;
InitializeTable(B, m, n);

...

for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    delete[] B[i];
delete[] B;
```

That being said, a better solution would be to not use raw pointers at all, though.  You should use `std::vector` instead:

```
void InitializeTable(std::vector<std::vector<char>> &B, int m, int n)
{
    B.resize(m);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        B[i].resize(n);

        for (int j = 0; j < n; i++)
        {
            B[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }

    // alternatively:
    // B = std::vector<std::vector<char>>(m, std::vector<char>(n, ' '));
}

...

int m = strX.length();
int n = strY.length();

std::vector<std::vector<char>> B;
InitializeTable(B, m, n);

...
```